# Program reading input in reverse order

Tags: c

I wrote a simple C program which reads space separated integers from `stdin`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int k, n, a[5], i = -1;
    printf("Enter K and N: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &k, &n);
    printf("Enter the values: \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[++i], &a[++i], &a[++i], &a[++i], &a[++i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you enter `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, the output given is `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`. If you don't use `i` while taking the input and use the values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` instead, the inputs are taken in normal way. I want to understand why is the program behaving so.

Screenshot of output:

[image]

Comment: I did not understand why did you take K and N from the user. by the way your code works fine and prints normally.

Comment: @reshad please ignore that, the program is incomplete. I'm using g++ compiler on Xubuntu 16.04 and it prints the output in reverse order for me.

Comment: for me if prints out in the correct order, but if you say so, try this
for (i=4; i>=0; i--)
 {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }

Comment: @reshad added screenshot, I know your approach should work but that isn't the problem. I'm seeking an explanation.